# AppGallery Console :The Deeplink created with the REST API service are not showing on the AG Console

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

Not able to see Deeplink created with the REST API service on the AG Console

Comment: Can you provide some detail log info for us to check?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Huawei [App linking documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/applinking-create-0000001141716380#section12351336145210) there is some restrictions.

- Callers of this API include account holders, administrators, app administrators, and development and operations personnel.
- Links created through REST APIs are not displayed in AppGallery Connect.
- Restrictions on API calls:

  - 5 times/second for each IP address
  - 1000 times/hour for each IP address
- Restriction on link quantity: 100,000 short links/day for each project